# c++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what(): Resource deadlock avoided when join thread

Tags: c++, signals

I'm writing a simple test code for signal handle. I produce a SIGSEGV in a child thread, and handle the signal.
But the error `std::system_error'   what():  Resource deadlock avoided` makes me so confused. Why there is resource deadlock?

```cpp
struct TestSignal{
  static TestSignal& GetInstance(){
    static TestSignal t;
    return t;
  }
  void Start(){
    t = std::thread([this](){
        // cause a SIGSEGV
        std::cout << *(int *) 0;
    });
  }
  void Stop(){
    if (t.joinable()){
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
    t.join();
  }
  std::thread t;
};


void HandleSignal(int signum){
  std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;
  TestSignal::GetInstance().Stop();
  exit(signum);
}

int main() {
  TestSignal::GetInstance().Start();
  signal(SIGINT, HandleSignal);
  signal(SIGSEGV, HandleSignal);

  pause();
}
```

Comment: Installing handlers only after the launching the thread is not a very safe thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal handler is called in the context of the thread t. You can't call `t.join()` in the thread routing, it would cause deadlock, thus you get program terminate, this way the deadlock is avoided.

Comment: Is there some recommend way to handle signal avoiding the deadlock caused by t.join?

Comment: You can use synchronisation primitives, leave the signal handler immediately and call `t.join()` in the main thread. In your particular example you can call `t.detach()` before pause.